# Question Regarding Highlighting only the Highest Value Per Row on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I have a data set I'm working with regarding sales figures. I have a 7 by 31 table on Google Sheets that I'm attempting to do the following with: Highlight to highest value PER ROW in a different color than the rest of the table.

Here's the issue: I have quite a few rows with no data in them because there aren't any sales for those days. The current formula I use will highlight the highest value on each row, but it will also highlight the entirety of a row that has 0 as the value of each cell. The whole point is to highlight those specific cells and with the conditional formatting highlighting like 70% of the table, it kind of ruins the idea.

Does anyone know of a better formula that I can use to avoid getting all of the non-value rows highlighted as well?

I've already monkeyed around with it for an hour, unfortunately sheets isn't my expertise for functions this specific so I'm S.O.L.  The formula I'm currently using is this:

=(K8=MAX($K8:$P8))*(1<>"")

Not sure what would need to be modified to highlight just rows with actual data in them. Please let me know if there's something I can do. Thank you very much in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why you created your last parenthesis, but you can use it also to make it be different than 0:

```
=(K8=MAX($K8:$P8))*(K8<>0)
```

Or different than "" if it's empty:

```
=(K8=MAX($K8:$P8))*(K8<>"")
```

RESULT without that last condition:
[image]

And with the condition:

[image]